# How can I repair cracked masonry window sills?

Tags: hole-repair

I live in Victorian house and noticed vertical crack on both external window sills. The ground floor one has a hole underneath. Is it serious problem? What to do?

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with evaluating a crack you just noticed in a 100-year-old sill is you don't know how long it's been like that or how fast it's changing.
It would probably be rare to not find something that has shifted over a century or more.

The top of the crack has been filled.

Keep an eye on it to see if it gets any worse.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tetsujin about watching for further movement, but you could improve appearance and reduce water and pest intrusion with some paintable caulk. I prefer urethane for this, but be aware that it's *extremely* sticky and will remain on anything it touches.

Fill the void and trowel it flat with a putty knife or scrap of wood or cardboard.